# FastText class uses undefined object

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

I came across the FastText class while reading an article that I found here...

https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-working-with-facebook-fasttext-library/#disqus_thread

The author has used an undefined object "word_tokenized_corpus".

```
ft_model = FastText(word_tokenized_corpus,
                      size=embedding_size,
                      window=window_size,
                      min_count=min_word,
                      sample=down_sampling,
                      sg=1,
                      iter=100)
```

I am getting an error for obvious reason. How do I correctly initiate the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article has been updated by the author and the following code was added:

```
final_corpus = [
    preprocess_text(sentence)
    for sentence in artificial_intelligence
    if sentence.strip() != ""
]

word_punctuation_tokenizer = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
word_tokenized_corpus = [
    word_punctuation_tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in final_corpus
]
```